# add waf libraries to pycharm

Tags: pycharm, waf, ns-3

I've installed NS3 and Waf and it's working correctly. but I should use basic editors like vim to write a **python** code! 
Is there any way to configure pycharm so that I can have NS libraries in it?

I've configured Eclipse and netBeans for C++, but pycharm confused me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question resolved and I write the answer for other guys if faced this problem.

you just need to run pycharm from waf shell! there is no need for other kind of configurations.

to access waf terminal:

```
./waf shell
```